# how can i get the edited package.xml after editing and saving it?

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used cat package.xml to create a package,then used gedit to edit it, after that I have saved it....how can I open this new saved package from the terminal again...thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245268/how-can-i-get-the-edited-package.xml-after-editing-and-saving-it?/) by [Ceasar](https://answers.ros.org/users/28185/ceasar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`gedit /path/to/your/modified/package.xml`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2